# scipy.io.loadmat nameerror in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I got this error whenever I run the code. I have used the absolute path of the data set in "loadmat" function. But I got the name error with that function. Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: A bad filename will produce a `FileNotFoundError`.  A `NameError` is caused by using an undefined variable.  Be more specific about the error and the cell contents.

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.